# Trying to obtain embedded flash memory on MCP5554 microcontroller

Tags: memory, disassemblers, digital-forensics, dumping

I am capable of dumping flash memory directly from EEPROM; however I am trying to pull data from a microcontroller that has an embedded 2 Mbyte flash in it. I understand that JTAG is one way to go.

Do I need the circuit board that is hosting the microcontroller to be intact for this? Can I pull the microcontroller off and go directly through the jtag pins on the controller? I am new to this and google searching hasnt turned up much, any help or a push in the right direction would be tremendous.

Comment: on most MCU's the MCU must be running for JTAG to use. you need power and possibly crystal + some capacitances and may be even some auxiliary power inputs handled. your best option without former PCB use is to have a some small SDK for the same MCU and swap them ... or just make minimal circuitry for your MCU on breading board or something with JTAG connection. If your MCU has ISP by serial or USB I would use that (less pins to attach to on former PCB) but they must be free of connection and MCU must not be protected by fuses